# Separate IntelliJ settings for projects

Tags: intellij-idea, configuration, settings, projects

I'm working on multiple projects at the moment and the fact that IntelliJ automatically synchronizes all settings makes life quite difficult for me.
For example, for project A I need to use a specific version of Maven with specific settings, for project B another version with other settings and for project C another version. This however isn't possible, when I set the Maven folder to something, it automatically syncs when I open a new IntelliJ.
This was just an example, there are more settings that I would like not to be shared.
Is there a way to resolve this?

Comment: Do you mean *Maven home directory*? Can not reproduce. How do you change it? Please describe the exact steps to reproduce the issue.

Comment: For example, Maven home, yes, I have 2 separate projects that need a separate Maven Home, Maven m2 Folder, settings.xml location, different Code Style, etc.